# Don't run apache2on startup

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I install apache2 from reps. But I need not to use it every day, only if I works on some application. How can I stop  auto running of it and run it manually if I need?

My OS is Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `sysv-rc-conf`, run it as root, and uncheck the boxes next to the `apache2` service.

Comment: @wombieis it way to do it without additional software?

Comment: Sure, rename the sysv symlinks by hand.  `sysv-rc-conf` is a lot nicer.  And you need to get a better font; my name is 'womble'.

Comment: I need to get better eyes:), sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update-rc.d` utility such as:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

To start it manually, you can use:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: The next time the package is upgraded, apache will start again on boot.  Please learn to use `update-rc.d` correctly.

Comment: @womble: Can you clarify your point please? Is there a better way to use this utility?

Comment: Yes, properly.  The manpage reveals all.